# Объединить несколько строк str_replace в одну

Tags: php

Вот, к примеру, код:

```
    $txt1=str_replace("`", "'", $_POST["txt"]);
$txt1=str_replace('&quot;', ' &quot& ', $txt1);
```

Как объединить эти несколько строк в одну?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае

```
$txt1  =str_replace("`", "'", $_POST["txt"]);
$txt1 .=str_replace('&quot;', ' &quot& ', $txt1);
```

Или

```
$txt1 = str_replace("`", "'", $_POST["txt"]);
$txt1 = $txt1 . str_replace('&quot;', ' &quot& ', $txt1);
```

Answer (score 0):

В PHP есть специальная функция объединения всех элементов массива в строку - `

```
> impode(varchar, array) //где
> varchar-символ, которым соединять
> элементы, а array-сам массив
```

В твоем случае получится примерно так:

> `implode(',',$txt1);`

`